# Home screen shortcut to another application

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut

I am making an app which makes a home screen shortcut for another app of mine if user has it installed.

It works partially. On API level less then 23 it works perfectly. On android 6 it creates the shortcut, but bypasses `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME` and `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE` and leaves original icon and name, which I don't want to use.

Here is the code example I am using:

```
ApplicationInfo selectedApp; //app that should be used for shortcut
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(selectedApp.packageName));
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "MyNewShortcut");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic1));
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Is there anything different that I should do on *Android Marshmallow*?

**EDIT**

Ok, this is a bit confusing. I managed to make it work somehow.
When I add this line:

```
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "asd");
```

It creates a shortcut on the main screen, but with name that I set on `addIntent`, and not `"asd"` like on the new line. Is there any logic explanation for that?

Comment: you can better to add run time permission also if you want use it in android  **M**

Comment: It is a normal level permission, not dangerous, so it doen't need runtime request. It is enough to set it in Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is some kind of a bug for Android **M**.

For shortcut to get new icon and name, I had to put extra name to the first intent too. And it could be an empty string because the name will stay from second intent. It is working like this now:

```
ApplicationInfo selectedApp; //app that should be used for shortcut

Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(selectedApp.packageName));
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "asd"); //EDIT additional string for first intent that fixes Android M

addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "MyNewShortcut");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic1));
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```